# Failed to add images in Tableau using URL that has no extensions

Tags: html, image, visualization, tableau-desktop

I was trying to create a dashboard using new image role function. However, I was struggled to add image using urls that don't have extensions (such as jpg,png etc.) included in the url. example:

https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5603AQF8paxRmnuJxg/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1517556808961?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=NBYea9Qtpy7LNtCZ0nC80pdz6NkOXXPGLnTNFL1QY_Y

I understood this is from LinkedIn and the link might change within certain period of time but this is accessible via web browser when I was testing this.

Wondering if you guys have any ways to display this image in Tableau.

I've tried modified the url by adding **''** but it's still not working. The image is also accessible by using 'Web Page' Object.

Comment: only valid hosted images as"file" is supported. the one you shared is an web object and not a file

Comment: do you know if there is any way I can convert the web object to a valid image url link without re-hosting the image on a publicly accessible place?

Comment: not possible, this is done to secure the images and compress them. if you want to host the image you need to do an entirely separate process